# get name of current PHP script in include file

Tags: php

I have files served like so:

AJAX request handler -> Include file

I would like to retrieve the name of the include file within the include itself. Neither `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is suitable for this, as they return the "parent" script name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
__FILE__
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not work on a setup with multiple linked servers. `__FILE__` shows the actual filename, but the path can be different that `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. On some servers this causes a 500 server error. I have not found a way yet to find the filename of the current included file relative to `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Answer (score 22):

If you want only the name part of the file (without the directory) you can use `basename(__FILE__)` or for just the directory `dirname(__FILE__)`.