# included php file to know it's file name?

Tags: php

lets assume i have include.php

which sometimes includes 1.php , 2.php , 3.php ....

i want a line of code , in each of the included files to know it's name (aka print 1.php if it is the included file) WITHOUT the need to modify include.php itself .

is it possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/php-get-the-current-script-file-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `__FILE__` constant.

```
echo __FILE__;
```

*See Also:*

- [Get name of current PHP script in include file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074944/get-name-of-current-php-script-in-include-file)
- [PHP Get the current script file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/php-get-the-current-script-file-name)

Comment: Making CW because this is almost certainly a duplicate, but I'm too lazy to search

Comment: Did the searching for you. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The following piece of code prints the current filename

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```