# Get filename and line number of start of function declaration

Tags: php, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out where a function is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222142/how-to-find-out-where-a-function-is-defined)
>   [included php file to know it's file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805521/included-php-file-to-know-its-file-name)

Can I get the **filename** and **line number** of the start of a function declaration in PHP?

Say, I have the following code:

```
 1. /**
 2.  * This function shows the foo bar.
 3.  */
 4. function foo_bar($subject) {
 5.     echo "Foo bar:\n";
 6.     if ($subject == "none") {
 7.         trigger_error("Wrong argument given to 'foo_bar()' in ... on line ....", E_USER_WARNING);
 8.     }
 9.     ...
10. }
```

When I call `foo_bar("none")`, the function must throw an error like this:

> **Warning:** Wrong argument given to 'foo_bar()' in /home/web/mcemperor on line 4.

Can I retrieve the **filename** and the **line number** of start of the function declaration?

Comment: @CodeCaster: disagree with that duplicate.  This is about knowing the line and file of where a function's defined, not the file name of the file that we're in...

Comment: @ircmaxell he wants a function itself (which is being executed, so `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are set) to show where it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [ReflectionFunction](http://us.php.net/reflectionfunction).

```
$r = new ReflectionFunction('foo_bar');
$file = $r->getFileName();
$startLine = $r->getStartLine();
```

It's that simple...  It works for any defined function, whatever one that you passed in to the constructor argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
$line = $backtrace[0]['line'];
$file = $backtrace[0]['file'];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: \_\_LINE__ is the current line, and not a "line number of the start of a function declaration"

Comment: Fair point. Added another method.

Comment: The same  : "line - integer - The current line number." http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Current depending on context, although I did get my array indexes the wrong way around. See the zeroth element in the first example. ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    ["line"] => int(10)

Answer (score 0):

The function name could be found with PHP exceptions, which are more interesting for error triggering : http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php