# With PHP include can you define the including page in the included page?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [get name of current PHP script in include file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074944/get-name-of-current-php-script-in-include-file)
> [Can an included PHP file know where it was included from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204830/can-an-included-php-file-know-where-it-was-included-from)

Does that headline make sense? :)

Can you determine the `PHP` page that you put the `<?php include 'SomeFile.php'; ?>` into, FROM THE INCLUDED PAGE??

In the page to be '`INCLUDED`' have an if statement based on the destination that grabs it?

Am I even saying this right?

Thanks All!

### THE SOLUTION:

### PAGEMAIN1.php

```
<?php
$MAIN2 ='';
$MAIN1 = 'MAIN1';
include 'PAGE1.php';
include 'PAGE2.php';
include 'PAGE3.php';
include 'PAGE4.php';
?>
```

### PAGEMAIN2.php

```
<?php
$MAIN1 ='';
$MAIN2 = 'MAIN2';
include 'PAGE1.php';
include 'PAGE2.php';
include 'PAGE3.php';
include 'PAGE4.php';
?>
```

### PAGE1.php

```
<?php
$PAGE1 = 'PAGE1';
if($MAIN1 == 'MAIN1'){
    echo '(This is PAGE 1 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 1)<br>';
    }
if($MAIN2 == 'MAIN2'){
    echo '(This is PAGE 1 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 2)<br>';
    }
?>
```

### PAGE2.php

```
<?php
$PAGE2 = 'PAGE2';
if($MAIN1 == 'MAIN1'){
    echo '(This is PAGE 2 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 1)<br>';
    }
if($MAIN2 == 'MAIN2'){
    echo '(This is PAGE 2 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 2)<br>';
    }
?>
```

### PAGE3.php

```
<?php
$PAGE3 = 'PAGE3';
if($MAIN1 == 'MAIN1'){
    echo '(This is PAGE 3 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 1)<br>';
    }
if($MAIN2 == 'MAIN2'){
    echo '(This is PAGE 3 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 2)<br>';
    }
?>
```

### PAGE4.php

```
<?php
$PAGE4 = 'PAGE4';
if($MAIN1 == 'MAIN1'){
    echo '(This is PAGE 4 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 1)<br>';
    }
if($MAIN2 == 'MAIN2'){
    echo '(This is PAGE 4 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 2)<br>';
    }
?>
```

### OUTPUT FROM PAGEMAIN1.php

```
(This is PAGE 1 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 1)
(This is PAGE 2 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 1)
(This is PAGE 3 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 1)
(This is PAGE 4 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 1)
```

### OUTPUT FROM PAGEMAIN2.php

```
(This is PAGE 1 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 2)
(This is PAGE 2 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 2)
(This is PAGE 3 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 2)
(This is PAGE 4 being "INCLUDED" in MAIN 2)
```

Just in case you wanted to know. ;) Thanks!

Comment: No idea what the dren you are talking about...

Comment: Oh, I don't get what the OP is asking. I'll just down vote it. ;)

Comment: +1 to remove the down vote someone added. A valid question that should make sense to anyone that reads it right. I hope the accepted answer helped you out. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is make a global variable that you use in all the pages that includes the subpage. In the subpage you can then check which page you are on. Does that make sense? ;-)

**page1:**

```
<?php
   $THISPAGE = "page1";
   include("subpage.php");
?>
```

**page2:**

```
<?php
   $THISPAGE = "page2";
   include("subpage.php");
?>
```

**subpage:**

```
<?php
   if ($THISPAGE == "page1")
      ...
?>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for reading what I posted, this was my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a set of [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) available to get that kind of information, but I don't think they cover what you want. Are you after something like:

mainfile.php:

```
<?php include('included.php'); ?>
```

included.php:

```
this page was included from <?php echo __PARENTFILE __ ?>
```

which would output

```
this page was included from mainfile.php
```

note: **PARENTFILE** does not exist and does not work. just making it up to figure out if this is what the OP means.